# MySQL 5.7 not accepting values of innodb_buffer_pool_instances greater than 1

Tags: mysql, innodb, buffer-pool, mysql-5.7

I've been tweaking the values of the buffer pool size (`innodb_buffer_pool_size`) and the number of buffer pool instances (`innodb_buffer_pool_instances`) in the my.ini initialization file to optimize heavy load handling with MySQL. I can successfully change the buffer pool size, both dynamically and with the my.ini file, but no matter what I change the `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` value to, it is always 1 when I query it with `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_instances;`

What I've already tried:

- I made sure to set the buffer pool size > 1GB. I've set it to 24GB and verified that it is indeed that big.
- Made sure I'm using the correct my.ini file location.
- After changing the value in my.ini I restart the MySQL server.
- I've even tried restarting my computer after changing the value, but it still always remains 1.

What am I missing? Why can't I change the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`?

Comment: are you using it in windows or linux? Let us know how you identified the ini file. Seem not referring to correct ini file.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. That was a problem at first, but I verified that I'm using the right .ini file. I can change the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, restart the MySQL server, and verify that it's correct. The file location is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\myl.ini.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I just reinstalled MySQL and now the variable updates just like it should. Don't know why it wasn't working, but I don't really care since it works now.